Why are non-type template parameters limited to structural types?
When using non-type template parameters, the non-type parameter must be 'structural' per the C++ standard. Classes with private data members are not structural. However, sometimes it is convenient to use private data members to protect a class invariant. Having a 'structural' restriction seems too restrictive. Consider the following code:
class A
{
    int data_priv;
public:
    int const& data() const { return data_priv; }
    int      & data()       { return data_priv; }
};

class B
{
public:
    int data;
};

template<A a> void funA() { } // Error: A is not structural
template<B b> void funB() { } // OK

int main()
{
    funA<{}>();
    funB<{}>();
};


What stops compilers from implementing (or the C++ standard from specifying) non-type template parameters with private data members?
In case there is some difficulty with comparing classes with private data members, would not be enough to define the comparison operator to allow non-type template parameters with private data members?
Edit:
Other related questions in Stack Overflow do not tackle these questions directly.

Just a note that there's another issue with your code: the non-static data members also need to be non-mutable.

Template parameters and template arguments: A structural type is ... a non-closure literal class type with the following properties: all base classes and non-static data members are public ...

They are non-mutable already: the keyword mutable does not appear. Class B works perfectly fine.

I guess it has nothing to do with implementability for the compiler. Rather, there must be some clear meaning of equivalence between two values of the type and  if a class has private members that means that it may have class invariants and therefore non-trivial equivalence meaning for its abstract states. It is not obvious anymore that distinct states of the member represent distinct states of the class.

This is hardly the same question, but I already answered it.
